# Security concerns when using git as a deployment utility

Tags: git, security, deployment

git is a very powerful tool, but not that easy to use

For example, I am glad to use git as a tool to update my remote site from my git repository. The problem is there is a .git directory at the root of my website, external users can simply visit it using site/.git, that is terrible, since they can easily get my code history, and basically the current code, they can even get passwords and private informations from the configuration files.

So what is the right way to use git which can make full use of git, but without introducing these threats?

Using `git clone git://repo site_root` to initialize web site, and `git pull` to get changes is of great convenience, but also brings huge security problems.

Is there any methods that can be as convenient as the steps shown above, but without security pitfalls?

Comment: Why are you using git to deploy your website instead of a deployment tool? Or simply having the .git directory not be browsable?

Comment: i use git clone to deploy the code since my web application is managed using git, git is really much better than ftp, since sometimes i can make modification on remote site, then i can commit and push that change to my git repo, also i can make changes on local pc, and then i can easily apply that change to server by simply using git pull, any other tool which can brings so much convinence?

Comment: Tracking private information and passwords is a security issue in and of itself: it makes it impossible for you to ever publish your repository anywhere.

Comment: it is usually the case that some configuration files contains sensitive data and they should be tracked by version control system, for example springContext.xml should contain database password in Java, and so is the case in other projects writen in other program languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not really fond of using directly git to automatically deploy the last version of your code, but that's another question.

Regarding your security issue, a really basic solution would be to just remove access to your .git file (with htaccess files?).

Another thing would be to remove your passwords from the git repository, there is probably no use of then in your version control system.

Comment: .htacess works, but it's error prone, since you should create .htacess in /site_root/.git/, but this file is not tracked by git, every time you deploy your web application, you should create such file manually, it's really boring, and sometime you may even forget to create this file, is there any easier way to create .htacess which can be tracked by git, it means i don't have to put .htaccess into .git directory, of course this configuration should forbid access to .git directory?

Comment: You can create a `.htaccess` outside of the `.git` directory. There's usually no need, as most Apache installs already prevent you from viewing `.anything` files.

Answer (score 2):

Apache, at least, defaults its configuration to forbidding web access to any file starting with a `.`, and this could be done in any other webserver as well.

Additionally, it's best to keep sensitive files outside the web root, i.e.:

```
.git/
config.file
public/
public/index.html
```

and have the document root for the site be the `public/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.clientcide.com/best-practices/exporting-files-from-git-similar-to-svn-export/

From the above:

> Here’s my one-line command for taking the archive and sending it to a
>   different location:
>
> git archive HEAD | (cd ~/path/where/I/want/it/ && tar -xvf -)
>
> This will extract the ENTIRE library to the specified path (without
>   the .git files and whatnot).
>
> Sometimes, however, I want to pull out just a portion of the library.
>   git archive always gives you the whole enchilada which kinda sucks,
>   and in this case I use rsync, like this:
>
> rsync path/I/want/to/export/ -ri --del -m --exclude ".*"
>   ~/path/where/I/want/it/ |grep sT
>
> That last bit – the grep sT will limit the output of what I see so
>   that I only see the files that are updated. I use that just to sanity
>   check my export. If I see a TON of stuff go to update a path that
>   already has the library and I know I only changed one file, then I
>   know I got the path wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of @JaredPar's comment, and @Chris Shain's answer above (+1 for the git archive).

I use `git archive` also, and then use Chef for the actual deployment. Couldn't be simpler.

1. `git archive <tag_name> | gzip > rc.tar.gz`
2. `mv rc.tar.gz` to my cookbook
3. upload cookbook

The chef-client running on my server runs the recipe to copy the zipped file to a chache location and extract it into my web server directory.

Note to self: publish the recipe on github

Answer (score 0):

If having the complete repo in the production server is a requirement, then there is a solution.

You can have the whole history somewhere in the file system and have git "point" to it.

```
$ cd /public                        # go to the public directory
$ git clone git://repo              # to initialize the web site
$ mv .git /private/repo.git         # move sensible information to a private place
$ export GIT_DIR=/private/repo.git  # make git "point" to the history
$ git pull                          # update changes
```

If you do that, your history will be in `/private/repo.git` that is not accessible through the web, and your working directory will be in /public, serving only the version of the files you specify.

For more information, you can read [progit](http://progit.org/2010/04/11/environment.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'll resurrect this question because I'm also looking into security issues.

You should use a detached work tree, as explained [here](http://www.deanoj.co.uk/programming/git/using-git-and-a-post-receive-hook-script-for-auto-deployment/). You can create your git repository outside the web root, and have git point to the source code at a different directory.